# Input as a default value for a function

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, default-value

Is it possible to have input as a default value for a function?

For example,

```
f(x=input('>')):
    print(x)
```

The problem is, it makes me input a value even when I supply an `x` value. How would I do this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python will *evaluate* the default arguments you define for a function, you'll get the prompt during definition either you like it or not. The value entered at the input prompt will then be assigned as the default for `x`.

If you want a default value that will use `input` if no other meaningful value is provided, use the common idiom involving `None` and drop `input` in the body of the function, instead:

```
def f(x=None):
    if x is None:
        x = input('> ')
    print(x)
```

Now, if you're thinking, I still want to somehow do this with default arguments, then you'll need to create a function that re-creates your function with every invocation:

```
def f():
    def _(x = input('> ')):
        print(x)
    return _()
```

I don't see what benefit this would bring other than appeasing your curiosity, though :-)

Answer (score 1):

May be this is what you want.

```
def f(x=None):
  if not x:
    x = input('>')
  print(x)
```